# script to extract files/folders from parent folder Win 7 , batch script

Tags: batch-file

Looking for ideas to help me with this.

I have a lot of music and most of it is in order of [artist folder] [album folder] [cd folder] [files] and I want to quickly be able to bring all music files under [artist] level.

I'm not expecting miracles so I'm thinking if I can set it up as a right click command much like WinRar does with Extract Here, that should bring everything from that folder up a level?

So I need to be able to

1. call my batch , and pass it the target folder.
2. Have the batch select all files/folders within and move to the
                           same level as target folder.
   Trying to keep it simple even if I need to r/click several times for one artist!

Thanks in advance for any help, pointers or further reading!

Comment: You have `\artist folder\album folder\cd folder\files` and files are **only** under the `files` folder, right?  Do you want to move them to `artist folder`?  Explain a bit further.

Comment: imo you need to add a menu item to the Windows explorer's context menu, [example](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-an-%22Open-With-Notepad-As-Administrator%22-Shortcut-to-the-Context-Menu-in-Windows-7-and-Windows-Vista).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script to move all files under a root directory to the root.
"Moveit.bat C:\my\music"
will find everything under that directory and move them into C:\my\music.

Line 27 is commented out ... so the script will only tell you what it would do.
Uncomment line 27 for it to actually work.

```
    @echo off
@rem USAGE: MoveIt root

setlocal

    pushd "%~1"
    set root=%CD%

    if "%1"=="" goto :Usage

    for /f "delims=;" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /s ') do call :MoveIt "%%a"

    goto :EOF

:MoveIt
    rem Exclude files directly under "from"
    set target=%~d1%~p1
    if "%target:~2%"==":\" (
        if "%target%"=="%root%" (
            goto :EOF
        )
    ) else if "%target:~0,-1%"=="%root%" (
        goto :EOF
    )

    echo move "%~1" "%root%"
    rem move "%~1" "%root%" > nul || echo Failed to move "%~1" to "%root%" & goto :EOF
    goto :EOF

:Usage
    echo Usage: moveit.bat  RootDirectory
    goto :EOF
```

Comment: Massive apologies folks, I completely forgot to check on this again. Foxidrive, even just extracting up one level would've sufficed, though an 'Extract to...' context would be awesome! 

Endoro, some good insight there, many thanks!

joeking, Many thanks for your time! Code looks like what I'm after, I'll give it a bash and report back within a decent timeframe this time! ;)